# c# Entity framework refresh combobox after adding data from another form

Tags: c#, entity-framework, combobox, visual-studio-2015

i'm using this code to load data from database to combobox

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
 comboBox1.DataSource = Dbcontext.Products.Tolist();

 comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ProductName";
 comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID"; 

}
```

when i add a new product from another windowsForm in the same project , when i come back to select the value from the combo box I can't found it. and this refresh won't work

```
privatevoid ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {         ComboBox1.Refresh()     

   }
```

how can i do this? thank you

Comment: You should invoke the database call when each time a new product is added or you invoke load when ever you come back to the page.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `AutoPostback` property to true will cause it to postback

you need to be sure to load the `dropdownlist` only if (!ispostback)

[ListControl.AutoPostBack Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback(VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use ComboBox1.UpdateLayout() method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to repopulate the comboBox1, when you move from that screen to this screen.

Your combobox datasource doesnt contain the newly added item. 
"Dbcontext.Products.Tolist()" populates the present products but isnt binded to fetch the newly added ones.

You need to perform that action manually.
Call a method on your current window like this

```
void RefreshData()
{
 comboBox1.DataSource = null;
 comboBox1.DataSource = Dbcontext.Products.Tolist();
}
```